# Deploying outlook add-in as an admin removes iOS support

Tags: ios, deployment, outlook, add-in

I have a simple task-pane Outlook add-in. When I install it manually (uploading the manifest file) to one account, it works well : on Outlook Desktop, Outlook online, OWA, and the iOS Outlook app.

When I install it to the whole organization through the Microsoft Exchange Admin Center (Organization --> Add-ins --> Add), two stranges behaviors occur :

1) It is immediately deployed to all accounts ; except for the administrator himself (~3 hours of delay before it is deployed !). Why ?

2) Once deployed, the Outlook iOS app support disappears, whereas the uploaded manifest is the exact same file. Desktop, Web, and OWA apps works well. The add-in indeed appears in the "Parameters > Manage add-ins > My add-ins" of each user.

I can't find or explain this problem. Did anyone find a solution or an explanation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delay can actually affect all users. We cache installed add-ins server side for performance improvements.

In terms of the add-in on ios, the scenario of admin installing add-in to mobile is currently not supported. This is in our backlog, and we'll be getting to this soon.

Comment: I just checked : it doesn't appear in the parameters > add-ins on iOS. On Exchange Admin Console, i uploaded manually the manifest, and set the add-in to be 'mandatory for all users'. I am currently trying to set it to optional to see if it appears... but i need few hours to remove it and retry for your cache reasons. I let you know asap !

Comment: Same problem for other type of installation : i put 'optional', it appears as "activable" on outlook.office.com. But nothing appears in the parameters of outlook iOS still. Any ideas of the reasons ?

Comment: Right, but do users see the add-in in their list of available add-ins in OWA or Outlook in client store? If the user turns the add-in on there, does the user then see the add-in in mobile as well (may have to kill the mobile app and relaunch it)?

Comment: Once activated on Outlook, online, it still doesn't appear on iOS app, even in the parameters. Even after two days.

Comment: Thanks. After looking into this more - the scenario of having an admin push out add-ins to iOS is currently unsupported. We have this queued up in our backlog.

Comment: We've just released an update that now allows admin installed add-ins to be pushed to ios as well. If an admin installs the add-in, it will show up in the add-in settings screen on Outlook mobile, but will be disabled. The user will have to manually enable it.

Comment: I did try yesterday the admin upload of my addin. But it seems for the moment nothing happened : it is on OWA, Desktop. But not appearing in the settings of the iOS Outlook app...

Comment: Any feedback from other users @AndrewS ?